# VMware view client don't run on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, vmware

After installing the `VMware-Player-4.9.0-9507999.x86.bundle`, the following error message occurs:

> vmware-view
>   /usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view-crtbora:
>   symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to install VM Player 14.

That version I could install in Ubuntu 18.04 without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I try to install the vmware view client. It works fine in version ubuntu 16.01 
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=CART19FQ3_LIN32_490&productId=578&rPId=25730